# Solution verification: $ \lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { 2 x - 6 } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } = ? $

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

This limit is not too difficult but I was just wondering if my work/solution looked good?

Thanks so much for your input!!

$$ \lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { 2 x - 6 } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } = ? $$

$$ 2 x - 6 = 2 x \left( 1 - \frac 6 { 2 x } \right) $$

$$ \lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { 2 x - 6 } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } =
\lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { 2 x \left( 1 - \frac 6 { 2 x } \right) } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } =
2 \cdot \lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { x \left( 1 - \frac 6 { 2 x } \right) } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } =
2 \cdot \lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { x - 3 } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } $$

By rationalizing the denominator:

$$ \frac { x - 3 } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } = \sqrt x + \sqrt 3 $$

$$ 2 \cdot \lim _ { x \to 3 } \frac { x - 3 } { \sqrt x - \sqrt 3 } =
2 \cdot \lim _ { x \to 3 } \left( \sqrt x + \sqrt 3 \right) $$

By plugging in $ x = 3 $:

$$ 2 \cdot \lim _ { x \to 3 } \left( \sqrt x + \sqrt 3 \right) =
2 \left( \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 3 \right) = 4 \sqrt 3 $$

Comment: Looks fine. Multiplying numerator and denominator by conjugates is a common trick for these limits. (by $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3}$ in this case)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: the OP is not using that. A denominator $x-3$ appears nowhere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: to be fair, "[rationalizing the denominator](http://tinyurl.com/yahz6oz3)" usually indicates multiplying the numerator and denominator by conjugates. In the subsequent equation, the numerator and denominator either were multiplied by $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt3$ and then the $x-3$ was cancelled, or were both divided by $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt3$. Since the author said "rationalizing the denominator", it is reasonable to infer that the author had done the former. However, as you say, the author did not explicitly say $\frac{(x-3)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt3\right)}{x-3}$, so we don't know for sure.

Comment: @robjohn: right, we don't know for sure.

Comment: One thing to note is that $\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt3}$ is not equal to $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt3$ when $x=3$, so $\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt3}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt3$ only for $x\ne3$. For $\lim\limits_{x\to3}$, we don't worry about $x=3$, so it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Shortly: for $x\ne\sqrt 3$,

$$\frac{2x-6}{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}=2\frac{(\sqrt x-\sqrt3)(\sqrt x+\sqrt3)}{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}=2(\sqrt x+\sqrt3)\to4\sqrt3.$$

Comment: Thanks so much! However, I'm a little confused about which part of my solution this is replacing, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Eight8: the whole.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok, but a bit verbose.

To remedy to that, I personally suggest working around zero by setting $x=3+u$ with $u\to 0$, I find it triggers natural reflexes more. Also for presentation purposes, I prefer working on the expression and then make use of $\to$ to specify the limit rather than carrying the $\ \lim\limits_{x\to 3}\ $operator everywhere, and the fact the the limit is now in zero helps a lot (it makes the context obvious).

Compare how much shorter this is:

$\require{cancel}f(x)=\dfrac{2x-6}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{2u}{\sqrt{3+u}-\sqrt{3}}\overset{(*)}{=}\dfrac{2\cancel u}{\cancel u}(\overbrace{\sqrt{3+u}}^{\to\ \sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{3})\to4\sqrt{3}$

$(*)$ multiply by conjugated quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution is correct. The only minor stylistic change I would personally consider is not going into as much detail when factoring out the 2 in the second line, and mention that you're multiplying your fraction by $\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3}}.$

Comment: This is not really what he is doing. He is simplifying by $\sqrt x-\sqrt 3$.

Comment: I expected this reaction. The expression has the pattern $\frac{t^2-1}{t-1}$ and the "conjugates" trick would be $\frac{t^2-1}{t-1}\frac{t+1}{t+1}$, possibly leading to the dead end $\frac{t^3+t^2-t-1}{t^2-1}$. More appropriate $\frac{t^2-1}{t-1}=\frac{(t+1)(t-1)}{t-1}$. And again, the OP didn't use the conjugates.